# How to use idxmin() to return USABLE index for pandas Series object

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dask

I am simply trying to  return the index of the minimum value of a series (which just comes from a column of a Dask Dataframe), and then use that index to access a corresponding value  in a different column of the same Dataframe. (I.e. the value at the same index.) I am also doing some intermediate math in this process.

I am using the following code:

```
start_time = Dataframe['time'].sub(c1).pow(2).idxmin() 
end_time   = Dataframe['time'].sub(c2).pow(2).idxmin()

#Now pull out data from a different column in Dataframe using start_time and end_time 

data = Dataframe['current'].loc[start_time:end_Time]
```

However I am consistently getting the following error:

```
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

I have no clue what this means, but one other thing that I noticed is that I have no grasp on what type of value `idxmin()` is returning. It is a completely mysterious object to me. When I try to print out the value of `start_time` or `end_time` all I get is:

`start_time:  dd.Scalar<series-..., dtype=int32>`

`end_time:    dd.Scalar<series-..., dtype=int32>`

I cannot find any specific information on these objects (although I've determined they are a "Scalar" object), and I cannot find any documentation on what methods or attributes exist for "Scalar" objects.

This is the crux of the problem because it appears that `idxmin()` is returning a data type that is unusable for indexing in Dask or pandas....real useful.

I've also tried

```
data = Dataframe.loc[start_time:end_time,'current']
```

This did not give an error, but `data` remains empty after this is executed.

Someone please set me straight.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`dd.Scalar` is a standard lazy value for a scalar.  You would get a similar object if you were to compute the sum or mean of a series.

You might try calling the `.compute()` method to see its concrete value.

Comment: When I use `.compute()` I get the error:  `ValueError: Usecols do not match names.`  The only thing I can think of is that, because I use the `usecols` argument in the `read_csv` function when I am creating this dataframe (to avoid storing every column in the csv file in memory) something is going wrong when I try to use `.compute()`. However I have no clue what, and so its hard to know if this solved the problem.